# How can I map a prop array that has been set in the useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to map an array that is in the form of a props from another component but I cannot get the data out. I seem to have done everything rightly but I cant see anything on my screen.

```
 const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [featuredProduct, setFeaturedProduct] = useState([]);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    return ()=>{
    const responseProductData = async()=>{
      const result =  await axios.get('/products.json')
      const data = result.data;
      setProducts(data)
      setFeaturedProduct(products.filter(product=>product.featured===true))
    }
   responseProductData()};
  }, [products]);

  
  return (
    <>
     <Header/>
     <Featured featured={featuredProduct}/>
     <Product/>
    </>
  )
```

I am setting featured to featured product for the featured component then in the component itself I am calling props.featured and trying to map it out but brings nothing. In the console, I can see the array but it keeps rerendering. I feel that might be the cause.

Still trying to get used to React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that you have `products` in the dependency array of the effect. This means that every time the `products` state changes, the effect is re-run. Which changes `products` again. So, your component is in a rendering loop.

You can use `data` directly rather than `products` in the effect so you can remove the dependency, which will fix the loop.

```
 const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [featuredProduct, setFeaturedProduct] = useState([]);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    const responseProductData = async()=>{
      const result =  await axios.get('/products.json')
      const data = result.data;
      setProducts(data)
      setFeaturedProduct(data.filter(product=>product.featured===true))
    }
   responseProductData()};
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <>
     <Header/>
     <Featured featured={featuredProduct}/>
     <Product/>
    </>
  )
```

Alternatively, you can figure out the featured product from the `products` with `useMemo` if you don't need it as a full stateful value.

```
 const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const featuredProduct = useMemo(()=>products.filter(product=>product.featured===true),[products])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const responseProductData = async()=>{
      const result =  await axios.get('/products.json')
      setProducts(result.data)
    }
   responseProductData()};
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for reponding. I removed the dependency but I get an empty array. It doesn't seem to be fetching the data on page load.

Comment: There was another thing that was bothering me. I noticed in the code that there was an extra `return ()=> {` before `const responseProductData`. Can you get rid of that return? You don't want to do the data call on effect clean up. You want the async function to be defined/called in the main body of the effect.

Comment: Thank you that works. I am just learning use effect and getting my way around it. I can see the data now but I cant map it weirdly enough. If I console.log props, I get a {featured: Array(1)}

Comment: Sounds like your data is coming back as an object instead of an array?

Comment: Yeah but if I console.log props.featured I get an array with an object that holds the value but I cant map that array out.

Comment: Seen the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a function from your [useEffect which will fire when you unmount the component](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1), so you won't see the data.

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

...

const getProducts = useCallback(async () => {
    const result =  await axios.get('/products.json')
    const data = result.data;
    setProducts(data)
    setFeaturedProduct(products.filter(product=>product.featured===true));
}, [setProducts, setFeaturedProduct]);

useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
}, [getProducts]);
```